# How to extract this function to not duplicate code

Tags: javascript

This code checks if the checkbox is enabled on site if it is disabled then it disable the textbox.

Function `disableTextBox()` is a `onclick` function and the `$(function()` is used to check the behavior of the checkbox after refreshing the page, I did not use the `localstorage` for that because sometimes different browsers are used.

How can I write this code better to do not duplicate it?

If the checkbox is checked then the textbox should be enabled, if the checkbox is not checked then the checkbox should be disabled for any input. It saves the checkbox after clicking save button (that is different functionality) not connected with this problem, and when the user back to the page it should check if the checkbox is checked or not and adjust the textfield.

Any ideas how to write it better or something?

```
$(function()
{
var checkboxField = document.querySelector('#checkbox');
var textBox = document.querySelector('#textBox');

if (checkboxField.checked == true)
{
    textBox.disabled = false;

}
else if (checkboxField.checked == false)
{
    textBox.disabled = true;
}
});

function disableTextBox()
{

var checkboxField = document.querySelector('#checkbox');
var textBox = document.querySelector('#textBox');

if (checkboxField.checked == false)
{
    textBox.disabled = true;
}
else if (checkboxField.checked == true)
{
    textBox.disabled = false;
}
}
```

Comment: You can use `textBox.disabled = !checkboxField.checked;` in place of your entire if-else block. And you can use `$(function () { disableTextbox(); });`

Comment: Why not just call disableTextBox function on the page's onload event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your `disableTextBox()` function, and instead of the `if/else` you could use the evaluated `boolean` result of `checkboxField.checked` straight ahead:

```js
function disableTextBox() {
  var checkboxField = document.querySelector('#checkbox');
  var textBox = document.querySelector('#textBox');
  textBox.disabled = !checkboxField.checked;
}

jQuery(function( $ ) {
  // Do it on DOM ready
  disableTextBox();
  // and on button click
  $('#btnDisableTextBox').on('click', disableTextBox);
  // Other DOM ready functions here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

prefering this way ;)

in this story every thing is boolean

Don't do testing if a boolean is True to déclare a true value for a if...

```js
const
  checkboxField = document.querySelector('#checkbox'),
  textBox       = document.querySelector('#textBox');

checkboxField.onchange = function()
{
 textBox.disabled = !checkboxField.checked;
}
```

```html
<label> modify texy <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked>

<textarea id="textBox"disable> blah blah bla</textarea>
```